# Accessing route params from two components on the same page

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I have a component (as shown below), which implements a fairly textbook subscription to the route parameters.

```
export class tutorialComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private sub: Subscription;
  public chapter: string;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.chapter = params['id'];
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

However, on the route: `http://localhost:3000/tutorial/chapter/0` if I run `ng.probe($0).componentInstance` from the browser (having selected the tutorial cmp), then I can see **chapter = undefined** - why?

Also, if I use `this.chapter = +params['id'];` then **chapter = NaN**?

## Update:

I have two components, a parent (Tutorial) and child (Chapter) component. The both have the same:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.chapter = params['id'];
    });
  }
```

however, the child component displays the `chapter` correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The suggested way per the documentation is to use the route.snapshot:

```
   this.validationCode = route.snapshot.params['id'];
```

which is from a working app...

Comment: I don't understand?

Comment: @JohnBaird - he means that the URL is dynamic, he needs an observer

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert `params['id'];` to a number like this:

`this.chapter = +params['id'];`

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't fix the issue, as a string, I get `undefined` as a number (i.e. your solution) I get `NaN`

Comment: So it means that nothing is passed to the route param `id`. If you can share some piece of code in plnkr, that might help.

Comment: So the child works and the parent doesn't work? Weird. I wanted to offer you to try `this.route.parent.params...` so you can get params from all parents, maybe you should try it just in case.